# 2021 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators, election

The 2021 Ham Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://ham.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: I have to say that the current election has me moderately concerned about the health of this stack.  Are my fears unfounded?  Perhaps this is like my local ham club; 90% of us are 55+, people are periodically active, but are still quietly active in their own way?

Comment: It appears that votes for candidates are secret, and we won't know until it's over. @DavidHoelzer Maybe the last paragraph means that we are supposed to ask a new question?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer There is a wide range of ages here.

Comment: Yes, sorry.  It was more a reflection than something that required someone to answer. :)